# Android MainActivity print/convert the value into 0/null?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Calc A = new Calc();
    int pIN = A.pIN();
    int pOUT = A.pOUT();

    System.out.println("IN : " + pIN);
    System.out.println("OUT : " + pOUT);

 }

}
```

clascc Calc - Not an Activity

```
public class Calc extends MainActivity {


public int PassIN;
public int PassOUT;

public String convertStringToHex(String str) {

    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();

    StringBuffer hex = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        hex.append(Integer.toHexString((int) chars[i]));
    }

    return hex.toString();
}

public String convertHexToDec(String hex) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < hex.length() - 1; i += 2) {

        String output = hex.substring(i, (i + 2));

        int decimal = Integer.parseInt(output, 16);

        temp.append(decimal);
    }

    return temp.toString();
}

public void Kappa() {


    String trnsferRP = "VDV2b0301";

    Calc strToHex = new Calc();
    String hex = strToHex.convertStringToHex(trnsferRP);
    Calc strToDec = new Calc();
    String dec = strToDec.convertHexToDec(hex);

    String cut = dec.substring(10);

    String A = cut.substring(0, 2);
    String B = cut.substring(2, 4);
    String C = cut.substring(4, 6);
    String D = cut.substring(6, 8);

    int cvA = Integer.parseInt(A);
    int cvB = Integer.parseInt(B);
    int cvC = Integer.parseInt(C);
    int cvD = Integer.parseInt(D);

    int calcA = (cvA - 48);
    int calcB = (cvB - 48);
    int calcC = (cvC - 48);
    int calcD = (cvD - 48);

    this.PassIN = calcA + calcB;
    this.PassOUT = calcC + calcD;
}

public int pIN(){
    return PassIN;
}

public int pOUT(){
    return PassOUT;
}

}
```

Result logcat

```
 07-21 01:29:10.672 26194-26224/com.example.kappa.passvalue2  W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
 07-21 01:29:10.672 26194-26224/com.example.kappa.passvalue2 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xae3e3580, error=EGL_SUCCESS
 07-21 01:29:20.426 26373-26373/com.example.kappa.passvalue2 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.kappa.passvalue2-1/lib/x86
 07-21 01:29:20.722 26373-26373/com.example.kappa.passvalue2 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.kappa.passvalue2-1/lib/x86
 07-21 01:29:20.772 26373-26373/com.example.kappa.passvalue2 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
 07-21 01:29:20.827 26373-26373/com.example.kappa.passvalue2 I/System.out: IN : 0
 07-21 01:29:20.827 26373-26373/com.example.kappa.passvalue2 I/System.out: OUT : 0
 07-21 01:29:20.837 26373-26399/com.example.kappa.passvalue2 D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
```

I have a problem to pass the value,I'm trying to pass the value calculated and converted from class Calc [not an Activity] to MainActivity to be used/prompt out.But the value became 0/null.. 
it should display (sample data)
IN : 3 
OUT : 1

so can anybody help me? or my method wrong on doing this?

already tried sharedpreference and intent bundle

Comment: where did you pass the value? Isn't that you just new a Calc instant and call pIn and pOut, without setting the PassIN, PassOut?

Comment: ooo so     
int pIN = A.pIN();
int pOUT = A.pOUT();  
not pass value? how to setting PassIN,PassOUT? 
sorry im new to android

Comment: in your Calc class, you can add a constructor, 
public Calc(int pin, int pout){
   this.pin = pin;
   this.pout=pout;
}
and then change Calc A = new Calc();
to Calc A = new Calc(3,1);

Comment: you can check here to see how to create constructor: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/class_constructor.html

Comment: thank you for the link,but as far i understand it really helps if we declare it example "3" but mine always changes..i tried to replace with other variable,but cant

Comment: If Calc is not an Activity, remove the extends...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting the pIN and pOUT values. Because you declared pIN and pOUT as public variables, you can set them like this.

```
Calc A = new Calc();
A.PassIN = 3;
A.PassOUT = 1;
```

As @brian661 mentioned above, you can also create a constructor that initializes the PassIN and PassOUT variables. In that case, consider making PassIN and PassOUT private since you would not need to access them directly:

```
public class Calc extends MainActivity {
    private int PassIN;
    private int PassOUT;
    public Calc(int PassIN, int PassOUT){
        this.PassIN = passIN;
        this.PassOUT = passOUT;
    }
    //rest of class
}
```

**Edit:**

Using the code you've provided, the only way to change `PassIN` and `PassOUT` is to call `Kappa()`.

```
Calc A = new Calc();
A.Kappa();
```

I'm guessing that the trnsferRP value changes, so you would probably want to change the signature of `public void Kappa()` to `public void Kappa(String trnsferRP)` so you can pass in the string instead.

Comment: sorry i'm confused, the variable will not always prompt out 3 and 1. 
this data VDV2b0301 (received by socket) will be convert into hexadecimal and decimal, so its not default this just a sample. if i declare like that it will always prompt 3 and 1.. so what im trying to do is the calculate data from class Calc to pass into MainActivity. the .Calc A = new Calc(); cant be applied.

Comment: @WafiIsmail See my edit to my answer. With the code you've provided, `int pIN = A.pIN();` and `int pOUT = A.pOUT();` do not do anything on their own. They will just return 0 since you never directly initialize PassIN and PassOUT. Only the Kappa() method changes PassIN and PassOut. You must call Kappa().

Comment: thank you, u have helped me crack my last puzzle.. been working since yesterday.. this is the last part that crash my app.. i appreciate and glad you help

now i understand it